# How to make graph out of seqential data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to whole elastic stack so pardon me if this is basic. But looking into docs I can't find way how to make following graph.

I am feeding elasticsearch with data that looks like this. `[{place:'a', time:0, user:1}, {place: 'b', time:1, user:1}, {place:'c', time:2, user:1}, {place:'a', time: 3, user:1}]` It is describing path which user went. So for this one `a->b->c->a`, and some other one could go `c->d->a->d->c`.

Is is possible to make graph with vertices made out of places and edges describing where users went?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create this visualisation, but its open issue in [github](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/8173)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to describe it in proper terms and thus not able to google it.